How to find a wire that's energized when Toyota hybrid is in Ready mode?
I've got a 2014 Toyota Auris hybrid. AFAIK, it is pretty much like a Prius under the hood.
I want to install a 12V to 230V inverter in the trunk, but only allow inverter to work when car is in Ready mode, to avoid draining the 12V battery. Inverter power input will be connected directly to the 12V battery, and it has contacts for an external on/off switch.
How can I find the wire that would have 12V potential only in Ready mode? My plan is to use that signal to control a relay that would enable my inverter.

Many circuits (often the radio for example) are only energized when the car is "running" (actual ignition in a conventional car, ready in a hybrid). Find one of those in the fuse box (or online resources). There are also low-voltage cutout switches made for this use as well.

I'm inclined towards looking at; 12v fuel pump power, ignition system power for spark and power for the engine ecm - all need 12v power but in a hybrid system, not powered up until a signal from the hybrid electronics determines the engine needs to run to begin recharging when the hybrid battery runs low or engine power is needed to supplement electric motor power (pedal to the floor scenarios).   You might find wiring online (Toyota Auris forums?) to have a better idea where READY mode occurs and if its a 12v signal to use as a control for switching on/off your inverter.
